# React-navigation-The term 'pod' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

My operating system(OS) is windows 10. I have created a React-Native project with the following code :

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
```

I want to install React-navigation then do the following steps :([based on the React-Navigation documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html))

1-

```
npm install @react-navigation/native
```

2-

```
npm install 
react-native-reanimated 
react-native-gesture-handler 
react-native-screens 
react-native-safe-area-context 
@react-native-community/masked-view
```

3- When I run the following step I get an error :

```
cd ios
pod install
cd ..
```

> pod : The term 'pod' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling  of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.

I do not know how to run the command above in windows.

**EDIT:**

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "testproject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.6",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-beta.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.56.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `pod install` command is for developing the iOS app which can only be done on Mac.

Since you're on Windows, you can't develop the iOS app. So you can skip this step entirely.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work unless you install cocoa pod on your system. Install cocoa pod using 
"sudo gem install cocoapods" this command.Follow https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html for further guidance. Also pods will be installed and only work in MacOS and not Windows OS.

Comment: I wonder if this is an answer to the question. You said it wont work in Windows OS so how this can be an answer?